Density function of nonuniform points' distribution over a unit sphere surface
I have read about picking random points on the surface of a unit sphere and found a statement about their density distribution, but I don't know how to prove it.
I want to prove that if I select spherical coordinates $\phi$ and $\theta$ from the uniform distributions $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$ and $\theta\in [0,\pi]$, the density of points will vary as $\dfrac{1}{\sin(\theta)}$. As I understand, it is connected with the fact that sphere segments area ($\mathrm d\Omega:= \sin(\theta) \, \mathrm d\phi \, \mathrm d\theta$) growing unevenly with the going away from the poles, but how rigorously prove this density assessment?
Can I somehow connect it with the parabola equation to describe density over a sphere as a conic function in polar coordinates from the $\theta$?

I think you are over thinking the problem. For uniform distribution in $\phi$ and $\theta$, the number of points is proportional to $d\phi\cdot d\theta$. The area covered by these points id $\sin\theta d\phi d\theta$. The surface density is number of points divided by area so it's proportional to:
$$\frac{d\phi d\theta}{\sin\theta d\phi d\theta}=\frac1{\sin\theta}$$

thank you, I guess the only thing I don't really get why we can devide by these infinitesimals...

and why the number of points is proportional to $d\phi d\theta$, is it true for sampling points infnitly many times from the intervals?

If you sample uniformly in $\phi$ and $\theta$ say from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $0$ to $\phi$, and you choose $N$ points, then the number of points in any region of size $d\phi\cdot d\theta$ is $$\frac N{2\pi^2}d\theta d\phi$$As for why you can divide, just think of those as small, finite regions $\Delta\phi$ and $\Delta\theta$, in the limit when those tend to $0$.

okey, thx, but why then we are excluding constant $\frac{N}{2\pi^2}$ from the density proportion? because it is a constant and doesn't affect anything?

Correct. The density of points will depend anyway on the number of tries.

then is it possible to somehow say, that density of points depending from $\theta$ as second degree polynomial? something like a parabola, for $x$ equal $\theta$ and $y$ number of points in some fixed small $\epsilon$ neighborhood?

I think so. You just write the Taylor expansion of $1/sin\theta$ around some $\theta_0$.
